# Remove empty rows from Grid

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code which removes blank rows from a Devexpress Datagrid.

```
 Private Sub btnRemoveBlanks_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As ItemClickEventArgs) Handles btnRemoveBlanks.ItemClick
    Try
    Dim I As Integer
        For I = 0 To StudentsGrid.DataRowCount - 1
            Dim CellValue As Object = StudentsGrid.GetRowCellValue(I, "FirstName")
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CellValue.ToString) = True OrElse CellValue Is Nothing OrElse CellValue Is DBNull.Value Then
            ' Debug.Print("Empty")
            StudentsGrid.DeleteRow(I)
        Else
            ' Debug.Print("Not Empty")
        End If
        Next
    StudentsGrid.RefreshData()
    btnRefresh.PerformClick()
     Catch ex As Exception
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error: " & System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
     End Try
End Sub
```

However, one problem is that I am receiving

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

on the line starting: `if string.isnullorwhitespace`

Or I have to click the button two or three times to remove all the blanks.

Is there a better way to determine if the row is empty or whitespace? Any ideas how I might improve this code?

Edit: The primary reason for the question was to remove the blanks, which I was able to do by stepping backwards through the grid

Comment: If IsDBNull(CellValue) OrElse CellValue Is Nothing OrElse ...

Comment: You need to reorder your checks so that `CellValue is Nothing` comes first... You can't check its `ToString() ` method if it's null. You also need to loop backwards instead of forward, otherwise once you delete a row, your index value will be out of sync. If you must go forward, you'll have to adjust the value of `i` manually after you delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want two different things:

1. The null reference exception is resolvable by reordering the conditions in your `If` command.
2. The need to rerun the removal multiple times is due to how you iterate over the rows. Your `For` loop iterates up to the number of rows in your grid view. Let's say you currently look at row `4` and decide to delete it. Now the row with former index `5` takes that position (the index of every following row is reduced by one). In the next iteration you look at index `5` which is now the row that has had index `6`, which means you will never look at the original fifth row. To resolve this *reverse your loop*.

Try this slightly changed version of your code (untested):

```
Private Sub btnRemoveBlanks_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As ItemClickEventArgs) Handles btnRemoveBlanks.ItemClick
    Try
        Dim rowIdx as Integer = StudentsGrid.DataRowCount - 1
        For i as Integer = rowIdx To 0 Step -1
            Dim CellValue As Object = StudentsGrid.GetRowCellValue(I, "FirstName")
            If CellValue Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(CellValue) OrElse String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CellValue.ToString()) Then
                ' Debug.Print("Empty")
                StudentsGrid.DeleteRow(i)
            Else
                ' Debug.Print("Not Empty")
            End If
        Next
        StudentsGrid.RefreshData()
        btnRefresh.PerformClick()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error: " & System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```